# Ember Validations stopped working after updating to ember-cli@0.2.3

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

```
import EmberValidations from 'ember-validations';
```

After updating to ember-cli@0.2.3, I am no getting the following error for the statement above:

```
Could not find module `ember-validations` imported by ...
```

It seems like it can`t find the import at all, any Ideas why?

Comment: I think you've install it using npm not bower. You can import bower packages like this. But to import npm package, you should use `ember-browserify`.

Comment: from their documentation "If you are using ember-cli you can add ember-validations to your package.json:"

Comment: I'm using ember cli 0.2.3 and I recently faced same problem when importing an npm module. I solved this using [ember browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-browserify). Using it you can import the module in the same way you import bower modules. `import MyCoolModule from "npm:my-cool-module";` . In near future bower will be deprecated in Ember CLI for managing dependencies in favor of Ember Browserify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `ember-addons.bs_for_ember` was causing this issue.  I removed this dependency form my Brocfile.js and then everything worked.